# Word for epigraph at the end of a book?

Tags: single-word-requests

From Wikipedia:

> In literature, an epigraph is a phrase, quotation, or poem that is set at the beginning of a document or component. The epigraph may serve as a preface, as a summary, as a counter-example, or to link the work to a wider literary canon, either to invite comparison or to enlist a conventional context.

Is there a similar but different word for the same which is placed instead at the end of a book?

Comment: I don't think this word exists. Could you give an example of a book and the relevant part of its back matter where this word, if it were to exist, would apply?

Comment: In *If You're So Smart: The Narrative of Economic Expertise* by Donald (now Deirdre) McCloskey, between the last chapter and "Works Cited", there is a short passage by a writer named Damon Runyon.

Comment: There's nothing that says an epigraph necessarily appears at the beginning. It's still epigraphical even if it appears at the end, or for that matter, anywhere else. Its position in the beginning is no more than  incidental and conventional.

Comment: A lot of definitions (e.g. Wikipedia) say an epigraph occurs at the beginning of a text, but that doesn't appear to be a universal opinion - see https://thewritepractice.com/epigraph/ and https://texfaq.org/FAQ-epigraph So using the word "epigraph" may be technically correct but may also be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

**epilogue**
[ODOL](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/epilogue):

> (*US* epilog)
>   noun
>   **1** A section or speech at the end of a book or play that serves as a comment on or a conclusion to what has happened.
>       *‘the meaning of the book's title is revealed in the epilogue’*

[WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epilogue):

> An **epilogue** or **epilog** (from Greek ἐπίλογος epílogos, "conclusion" from ἐπί epi, "in addition" and λόγος logos, "word") is a piece of writing at the end of a work of literature, usually used to bring closure to the work

An epilogue need not be, and usually is not, epigrammatic.